# Is there a node forever equivalent for yarn?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, yarnpkg, forever

Right now I'm using `screen` in order to run my command `yarn run dev-server`.

I'm looking for an equivalent to something like:
`forever start app.js`

Except for `yarn run dev-server`.

`dev-server` in package.json is = `"dev-server": "webpack-dev-server"`

As everyone knows if the program crashes in `screen` it doesn't automatically restart.

Side note, it's a react web framework.

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion around [yarn] and [yarnpkg].

Answer (score 1):

On an Ubuntu server, I would recommend to use [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) for running your NodeJs application.

[This article](https://www.shellhacks.com/systemd-service-file-example/) has some examples how you can write a systemd unit file. If the process dies, systemd will detect it and automatically restart it.

Untested (but to sketch the idea):

```
[Unit]
Description=Example server

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/my/server
ExecStart=/usr/bin/yarn run dev-server

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Although running it through `yarn` is a bit weird. In a production setup, I have not seen it. Normally, you execute the server by directly running it with node (e.g., `node server.js`).

Comment: Its odd because the script doesn't work with node, only yarn.

Comment: @MarcAlexander webpack-dev-server is normally for development only. I have only seen it being used on local developer's machine. When you run commands through yarn (or npm), it can use binaries in node_modules. I think, in your case it calls the node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server binary in the end (source: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/ )

Comment: I see. This isn't my script. A client wants me to put it up to demo purposes and I don't want it to crash and not restart on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

> PM2 is a daemon process manager that will help you manage and keep your application online 24/7 
>   And for the use with yarn

```
pm2 start yarn --interpreter bash --name api -- start
```

Comment: You don't need bash for this. A simple `pm2 start yarn -- run dev-server` would work just fine. And Oh, there's a mistake in your example - the arguments are `run dev-server` not `start`